# load an ad (div) just once on first load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to know how can I have a div that has an ad to load or become visible ONLY the first time you load the page but hide it every time the page is refreshed?

I only have the code to load the div with Jquery but don't know how to hide it after refreshing the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".referralProgram").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Comment: So only show it once to every user? So if the user visits 20 days later don't show it to them?

Comment: Perhaps an alternative would be to always show the ad to non-logged in users. Logged in users could see it the first time but not again later. This would get around the cookie problems because you'll be storing the ad state server-side instead of in the client. Also gives other benefits such as permanence of state across any device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a cookie:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (!readCookie("adSeen")) {
        $(".referralProgram").fadeIn("slow");
        createCookie("adSeen", "1", 1000);
    }
});

function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Cookie functions from [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html#script).

**Edit:** Since so many are discussing how to deal with this if cookies are disabled, it should be pointed out that server session implementations rely on either a cookie, or a session identifier in the url.  At best, you could only prevent displaying the ad for the same user as long as the session identifier is in the url.  Returning to the home page sans session id would re-display the ad.  Additionally, a careless implementation (and even some careful implementations) could result in false positives for other users if a user shares a url.  `localStorage` solutions won't work with cookies disabled in most, if not all, browsers.

Comment: Thanks, a lot this will work, I don't have to worry about cookies because the clients that will see it must have it turn on to be able to log and see the other content available.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a way to keep track of when an ad has been displayed to the user. Set a cookie when the ad is created and check for it before displaying again?

Comment: The only thing that sucks about this type of implementation is that if the user has cookies disabled they get the pop-up every time. Not sure of a better way though. Most sites require cookies to do anything meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use client side persistent storage to flag the user has already seen this.  Here are 3 options:

1)  Cookies - Set a cookie on the visiting users machine.

2)  HTML5 Storage - You can store the flag in browser (HTML5 Only) storage.

3)  Server Session - If you are using middleware (PHP, ASP.NET, Java, etc.) you can track via a session variable (this is an abstraction of a cookie and is only as persistent as you create it to be).

Comment: #3 is not a good solution for Safari. Disabled 3rd party cookies. If the author's page is embedded in a UIWebView, *no* state will be saved client-side and the ad will always show.

Comment: I don't believe any answer (regarding cookies) provided will work if 3rd party cookies are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your server side implementation is like, but if you are worried about cookies being turned off you could handle this on the server side using session state.