# Show loading animation only on first time page load using Cookies?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, pageload

I have **loading animation** on my HTML page and it is working absolutely fine. The problem is whenever page gets refreshed, the loading animation appears again and  I want to limit it to only first time page load.

I was using cookies to solve the problem and I took reference from one of stackoverflow questions:
[load an ad (div) just once on first load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247150/load-an-ad-div-just-once-on-first-load). I was using the exact same code which is answered there, just replaced my id.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if (!readCookie("adSeen")) {
    $("#loading").fadeOut("slow");
    createCookie("adSeen", "1", 1000);
}});
```

Rest of the code is same. My cookies are enable, but it is not working. Help me to fix it.

Here's my code: https://jsfiddle.net/mytest_jsfiddle/ojo2mosd/5/

Comment: Have you defined `readCookie()` and `createCookie()`?

Comment: It works for me here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/3426k3sn/

Comment: Do you have the `#loading` image hidden in CSS?

Comment: Shouldn't it be fadeOut instead of fadeIn ?

Comment: Barmar & Prototype I have updated my question. Please have a look again. I have linked to my code as well.

Comment: @Barmar it is not an image and it is not hidden. I mistakenly set fadeIn rather than fadeOut. Look at my jsFiddle.

Comment: Your fiddle works for me. The first time I go to it, the animation fades out after 4 seconds. The next time it doesn't.

Comment: It seems like you're doing the cookie test at the wrong time. You say you only want to show the animation the first time. But you have the cookie check around the code that sets the fadeOut timer. You should check the cookie when starting the animation.

Comment: @Barmar it is working fine now. I cleared my entire browsing data and now its working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     if (!readCookie("adSeen")) {
    $("#loading").fadeIn("slow");
    createCookie("adSeen", "1", 1000);
}
    });

    function createCookie(name, value, days) {
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        } else var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
    }

    function readCookie(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

For reference, Please refer to the below fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/aman_chhabra/fguq4hnd/1/

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have update the fiddle. Its working fine for me for Fade Out as well. Please ensure that you don't have cookie in your browser as of now for this fiddle to work atleast once.
Or else check if cookies are allowed if it is always fading out.

Comment: I have tried everything but still it is not working for me. Maybe still I am doing something wrong. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/mytest_jsfiddle/ojo2mosd/5/. I have set some time, but now even it's not fading out. I am newbie to JS.

Comment: Even your fiddle worked fine for me. Just to be extra sure. Can you try this in incognito window, you can open it using

ctrl+shift+P - for firefox    
ctrl+shift+N- for Chrome

Comment: It working for me now as well. I cleared my entire browsing data. Thumbs up. Vote for my Q if you can.